# How do I unforbid all items

Tags: rimworld

Just started at RimWorld and I see an objective asking me to unforbid my resources. I have a ton of forbidden steel lying around and I was wondering if there is anyway to simply unforbid all steel? Or do I have to manually unforbid each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select an area with your mouse, and if you get no colonists in that area, it will select all items.  Then unforbid them all.

You can also doubleclick an item to have it select all on-screen items of the same type (so, doubleclick steel to select all steel) and mass unforbid that way.

Comment: Zoom out before you do this to maximize the effect.

Comment: Also valuable for harvesting large amounts of wild resources.

Comment: Obviously this does not address the items the game does not include in area-selection-mode.

Comment: @duane I haven't played in a while, I don't think there were items that were left out at the time I wrote the answer.